# rvm1/capistrano3 doesn't use gemset

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, ruby-on-rails-4.1, rvm-capistrano

I am trying to deploy a Rails 4 app to a VPS.

My Capfile, Gemfile, deploy.rb are in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/i-arindam/18fbf79da5adef10baaf)

On `cap production deploy` it fails bundle install step, because it doesn't use the gemset, and keeps saying gem not found.

The relevant output from `cap`

`INFO[90fcd8c1] Running /tmp/domain_spam_checker/rvm-auto.sh 2.1.2 bundle exec gem install --file Gemfile on 162.221.181.224
DEBUG[90fcd8c1] Command: cd /home/deployer/domain_spam_checker/releases/20140922153958 && /tmp/domain_spam_checker/rvm-auto.sh 2.1.2 bundle exec gem install --file Gemfile
DEBUG[90fcd8c1]     [31mCould not find i18n-0.6.11 in any of the sources[0m
DEBUG[90fcd8c1]     [33mRun 'bundle install' to install missing gems.[0m
cap aborted!`

...

`Tasks: TOP => deploy => rvm1:install:gems`

How to mention the gemset to use somewhere in the setup files ?

How to get rvm1/cap3 to pickup or create the gemset ?

Answer (score 1):

I've never tried `rvm1/capistrano3` so can't help you there but I suggest you use `capistrano/rvm` instead ([link](https://github.com/capistrano/rvm))

Capfile:

```
require 'capistrano/rvm'
```

deploy.rb:

```
set :rvm_ruby_version, '2.0.0-p247@mygemset'
```

Comment: I have upvoted your answer as it helped my solve my problem.

But can't accept it as it does not solve the asked question.
will leave it open for someone else to answer, so it may help others. :-)

Thanks very much